# tinyMCE : dynamic variables in the source view

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Is it possible to use dynamic variables in tinyMCE?

Here's the use case I have in mind:

1. User adds an image in source view like this `<img src="{imagepath}/logo.gif" />` or one is added programmatically using setContent().
2. User switches to design view - {imagepath} is expanded to http://someserver.com/ and the image is correctly shown with the expanded url.
3. User opens image properties - The url is shown as {imagepath}/logo.gif
4. User switches back to source view and the {imagepath} variable is still shown.
5. getContent() returns the source with variables intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, refer to the TinyMCE template plugin for a javascript solution - it already does it:
http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Plugins/template

For a server side solution, just do a search and replace on the strings you want. This can be in a for loop or via a regular expression. If you decide to use the server side solution, the TinyMCE non-editable stuff can come in handy too.